# How do I run an android application on a device

Tags: android, adb, eclipse-adt

I actually installed the drivers for my phone in the laptop
As I wanted to run my application on my phone
I followed the procedure of

```
run configuration -> android -> new configuration(1) -> always prompt device
```

But im not able to see my device on the screen
How to resolve this issue?

FYI: I have turned on the usb debugging on my phone

Comment: you don't probably have the right drivers

Comment: You are using Windows? I recently had success after installing the UniversalAdbDriver which can be found under https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

Comment: what phone is that ? looks like drivers are not properly installed ... also make sure your phone's developer option is activated